# Get post id in wordpress action?

Tags: posts, actions, customization

I have this code

```
add_action( 'delete_post', 'my_delete_function' );
 function my_delete_function() { 
   global $wpdb;
   $wpdb->query("
    DELETE FROM wp_votes WHERE post=".$thePostID."
;);
 }
```

How can I get the id of the post being deleted?

Additionally, will this still work if multiple posts are deleted in the admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested so I'm providing you with two possibilities, Inside a loop, use the following:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
```

Outside a loop, use the following:

```
global $wp_query;
$post_id = $wp_query->post->ID;
```

Or:

```
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID
```

Or you can pass the post ID in a function, much like

```
function my_function($post_id){
    // code
}
```

Comment: Inside the loop, it is probably best to use get_the_ID()

Comment: There's no reason **whatsoever** to use a solution other than the one passed as a function parameter - all others are void and risk breaking!

Comment: When you add an action this way, global $post will not get you the post nor will get_the_ID get you the post ID.

Answer (score 3):

Add a parameter to your function, which will be passed the ID of the current post being deleted.

```
add_action( 'delete_post', 'my_delete_function' );
function my_delete_function( $post_id /* <- ID of post being deleted */ )
{ 
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "DELETE FROM {$wpdb->prefix}_votes WHERE post = %d", $post_id ) );
}
```

Using any external variable (like a global in @Asko's answer) removes any guarantee that the post **actually being deleted** is the one you're working on within your function - it could either fail completely, or even delete data for the wrong post!